How to fix 404 error when deploying react-route-dom?
I am going to learn react and distribute a program for use in the company for the first time
The web server is apach
404 error is output when connecting after deployment
At first, I thought it was a server setting
const App = () => {
  return (
    <AppProvider contexts={[CommonProvider, ModalProvider]}>
      {/*<RouterProvider router={router} />*/}
      <div>test</div>
    </AppProvider>
  );
};

After annotating the router part, the word text is output normally when the distribution test is conducted.
If you release the annotated part of the code above and test it
Unexpected Application Error!
404 Not Found
test
It is printed in .
I guess 404 error is output on the route
route.js

import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Head, { ScheduleMainLoader } from "./../components/Head";
import ScheduleMain from "../components/ScheduleMain";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    //path: process.env.PUBLIC_URL,
    element: <Head />,
    loader: ScheduleMainLoader,
    children: [
      {
        //path: "/",
        index: true,
        //path: process.env.PUBLIC_URL,
        element: <ScheduleMain />,
        //loader: ScheduleMainLoader,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

export default router;

import CommonProvider from "./context/CommonContext.jsx";
import router from "./routers/routes";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import ModalProvider from "./context/modalContext";

const AppProvider = ({ contexts, children }) =>
  contexts.reduce(
    (prev, context) =>
      React.createElement(context, {
        children: prev,
      }),
    children
  );

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AppProvider contexts={[CommonProvider, ModalProvider]}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </AppProvider>
  );
};

export default App;


I tried changing the path from route.js to / and also changed it to process.env.PUBLIC_URL, but I'm still outputting the same 404.
How can I solve the above problem?

What is your production web server?

404s are server errors, not front-end library errors. Where and how are you serving your application? Where are you deploying it?

The web server is apache
I'm connecting with my company's ip.
http://ipadress/~userid

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing and React, BrowserRouter, Apache, and sub-directories.

Still really surprised the React Router docs don't have any section or FAQ on server-side URL rewriting for the BrowserRouter

@Phil How do you feel about writing documentation for open-source projects? I don't know what they'd cover that the CRA docs don't already document fairly well though.

I don't see any error messages, so it's frustrating where to start

@DrewReese CRA is a dead project and I'd expect the router docs to contain the relevant details. They used to have a guide but it got removed for some reason - https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md#configuring-your-server

@Phil I solved the problem.
Set ~userid on the route path and it becomes normal.
